# Collision detection for non-square objects

Tags: java, android, collision-detection

I have some lasers that use rectangles for hit boxes which I check for intersection with rectangle hit boxes with my enemies in a game. This works fine, but now I'm trying to implement some lasers that are at an angle of 30 degrees and I have no idea how to do this efficiently. I don't want to do per pixel detection as I'm planning of having quite some on screen and it would be to much.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Oh I'm doing this in java for android ( don't think it's that important though)

Comment: Can you provide some more detail about the geometry involved? A diagram would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate using linear intercepts

```
   y = mx + c
   y2 = gx + d
   mx + c = gx + d
   mx - gx = d - c
   x(m - g) = d - c
   x => (d-c)/(m-g)
```

Then test whether the returned value is in the domain of x. Once x is found, calculate y and test it's in the range of both the lazer and the rectangle